# Invalid implicit conversion from enum to enum

Tags: solidity, foundry, bug

My question is how is it possible to have such error:

```
Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from enum CoinType to enum CoinType requested.
  --> test/foundry/zrc20_interface.t.sol:16:46:
   |
16 |         zrc20 = new ZRC20("TOKEN","TKN",18,1,cointype,0,address(systemContract));
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

This is enum in Interface.sol

```
    enum CoinType {
        Zeta,
        Gas,
        ERC20
    }
```

This is a test case using Foundry framework

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import {Test, console2} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

import { ZRC20 } from "../../contracts/zevm/ZRC20.sol";
import { SystemContractMock } from "../../contracts/zevm/testing/SystemContractMock.sol";
import "./Interfaces.sol";
contract zrc20_interface is Test {
    ZRC20 public zrc20;
    SystemContractMock public systemContract;
    CoinType cointype;
    function setUp() public {
        cointype = CoinType.Zeta;
        systemContract = new SystemContractMock(address(0),address(0),address(0));
        zrc20 = new ZRC20("TOKEN","TKN",18,1,cointype,0,address(systemContract));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I have encountered this before.The `enum CoinType`  is defined in `Interface.sol`, but is `Interface.sol` being imported in any of `ZRC20.sol` or `SystemContractMock.sol`? . Becuase if it is then compiler is basically referencing two different memory regions. Remove the `import "./Interfaces.sol";` statement and try this :

```
import { SystemContractMock, CoinType } from "../../contracts/zevm/testing/SystemContractMock.sol";
```

and compile again.
For some reason with current version of Foundry `import {X} from "...";`  syntax is silently mandatory

Comment: Hmm, I will report this in Foundry Github. It would be nice to log error specifically as the current log is misleading

Comment: I think someone may have raised an issue already, perhaps run it by foundry telegram group first.